# Salt initializes differently each time server starts, trouble with credentials database in python bottle and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, hash, credentials, salt

First of all I am using Python bottle with Sqlite3. The trouble that I am having is that when I initialize my salt at the beginning of the program, and then stop the program and restart it, the whole thing breaks because it makes a different salt. So when I restart the program, I can't login with any of the old accounts, and I can't make a user with the same name because theyre still stored in the credentials DB.

salt:

```
salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

hash:

```
hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(passwordInput + salt).hexdigest()
```

I am verifying the account by

```
row = (c.execute("SELECT * FROM Credentials WHERE usernameDB =? AND passhashDB =?", (usernameInput,  hashed_password, ))).fetchone()
if row:
```

etc...

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Why are you creating a new salt at all? Just create one once, and write it as a literal string.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That is not the correct way to use a salt, it should be created for each account, but persisted with the account.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you're right of course, I was confusing it with a site-wide secret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all accounts had the same [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), it would not be able to protect against a rainbow table computed for this salt.
Each user must have its own salt.

The salt is stored together with the password hash in the database.
(The salt itself being stored unencrypted is not a problem; you need it again to check the hash.)

Something like this:

```
def new_user(name, password):
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    hash = hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Credentials(usernameDB,passhashDB,salt) VALUES(?,?,?)",
              (name, hash, salt))

def check_login(name, password):
    c.execute("SELECT salt, passhashDB FROM Credentials WHERE usernameDB = ?",
              (name,))
    for row in c:
        salt = row[0]
        actual_hash = row[1]
        input_hash = hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
        if input_hash != actual_hash:
            raise Exception("invalid password")
    else:
        raise Exception("invalid user name")
```

Comment: So two questions: 1.) With the salt at the very beginning of the program, every time I call the salt in the hashed_password initialization, is it going to create a different salt? If not, should I move the salt initialization into the `def createAccount` function?  And 2: How is the salt being unencrypted not a problem? Am I unencrypting the password wrong? Because the salt in the hashed_password and the OTHER hashed_password that I am testing it against are different every time I start the program up again.